# How can I force an Nvidia video driver reload on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, nvidia-graphics-card, display-driver

There is some bug between my graphics card and my monitor that results in the latter not being detected sometimes when Windows is booting up. I could really use a way to force reload the display driver and attach it to a keyboard shortcut. Is it possible?

Comment: Is it possible you have a faulty cable?

Comment: check out [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500411/force-windows-video-driver-reload-is-it-possible-at-all)

Comment: @JustinPearce No, it's a crappy video bios that Gigabyte won't bother to fix.

Comment: @Raystafarian That thread is about C#, which I know nothing about... so it's not much help for me

Comment: @user697683 Sorry about that, then. Hopefully someone comes along with some help.